# Geometry optimization

Tags: geometry

[image]

Three equilateral triangles with side lengths 28 are placed in the position as shown in the picture above. All the contacts are perfect and a circle passes by exactly one vertex per triangle. What’s the minimal radius?

Comment: Does this have a neat, puzzle-like solution?

Comment: Yes, it does have one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I believe the radius is:

> $84\left(\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{2}\right)\approx26.69832$

I get this by assuming that the centre of the circle is $x$ along the line between the two joined triangles on the right, and that the apex of the triangle on the left is horizontal with this, which I think is correct. [Solve for $x$ here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%2814-x%29%5E2%2B%2814*sqrt%283%29%29%5E2%20%3D%20%2814*sqrt%283%29%2Bsqrt%283%29*x%2F2%29%5E2). And [substitute back to get the radius here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sqrt%28%2814-x%29%5E2%2B%2814*sqrt%283%29%29%5E2%29%2Cx%3D28*%285-2*sqrt%286%29%29).

Comment: I’m sorry, but the answer is incorrect.

Comment: Okay, I fixed it. Was not thinking clearly...